# Count joined strings in dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

Given my list of dictionaries

```
dict_nomi = [
    {'first_name': 'Luca', 'last_name': 'Rossi'},
    {'first_name': 'Stefano', 'last_name': 'De Rosso'},
    {'first_name': 'Luca', 'last_name': 'Bianchi'},
    {'first_name': 'Luca', 'last_name': 'Rossi'},
]
```

I'd like to count the occurrences of values not by one key, but by multiple keys (two, in this case).

```
def count_names(dict_nomi):
  names = Counter(v['first_name'] for v in dict_nomi if v.get('first_name'))
  for names, count in names.most_common():
    print(names, count)

count_names(dict_nomi)
```

This gives me:

```
('Luca', 3)
('Stefano', 1)
```

But how can I get something like

```
('Luca Rossi', 2)
('Stefano De Rosso', 1)
('Luca Bianchi', 1)
```

this?

Thanks.

Comment: instead of accessing the dict in your list comprehension directly, you could write a function that gives you what you want; in this case firstname lastname: `func = lambda entry: entry["first_name"] + " " + entry["last_name"]`. that way you can switch it out easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just:

```
from collections import Counter

dict_nomi = [
{'first_name': 'Luca', 'last_name': 'Rossi'},
{'first_name': 'Stefano', 'last_name': 'De Rosso'},
{'first_name': 'Luca', 'last_name': 'Bianchi'},
{'first_name': 'Luca', 'last_name': 'Rossi'},
]
c = Counter(' '.join((d['first_name'], d['last_name'])) for d in dict_nomi)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'Luca Rossi': 2, 'Stefano De Rosso': 1, 'Luca Bianchi': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_names(dict_nomi):
  names = Counter("{} {}".format(v['first_name'], v['last_name']) for v in dict_nomi if v.get('first_name') and v.get('last_name'))
  for names, count in names.most_common():
      print(names, count)
  return names

names = count_names(dict_nomi)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

Counter([d['first_name'] + ' ' + d['last_name'] for d in dict_nomi])
out: Counter({'Luca Rossi': 2, 'Stefano De Rosso': 1, 'Luca Bianchi': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_nomi = [
{'first_name': 'Luca', 'last_name': 'Rossi'},
{'first_name': 'Stefano', 'last_name': 'De Rosso'},
{'first_name': 'Luca', 'last_name': 'Bianchi'},
{'first_name': 'Luca', 'last_name': 'Rossi'},
]

res = {}
for i in dict_nomi:   #Iterate over your dict
    val =  "{0} {1}".format(i["first_name"], i["last_name"])
    if val not in res:   #Check if key in res
        res[val] = 1     #Else create and add count
    else:
        res[val] += 1    #Increment count
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Luca Bianchi': 1, 'Luca Rossi': 2, 'Stefano De Rosso': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the Counter Dict from **`collections`** module in python.

```
from collections import Counter as cnt

dict_nomi = [
{'first_name': 'Luca', 'last_name': 'Rossi'},
{'first_name': 'Stefano', 'last_name': 'De Rosso'},
{'first_name': 'Luca', 'last_name': 'Bianchi'},
{'first_name': 'Luca', 'last_name': 'Rossi'},
]

cnt_dict = cnt(' '.join((dic['first_name'], dic['last_name'])) for dic in dict_nomi)

final_res = [(i,j,) for i,j in cnt_dict.iteritems()]
```

Output

```
[('Luca Bianchi', 1), ('Luca Rossi', 2), ('Stefano De Rosso', 1)]
```

Let me know if this solves your problem